# Merging two WAV files together with different durations so that the end times match

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I have several pairs of wav files (obtained by recovering the audio from VoIP packet captures). I'd like to merge the two files down to a single-channel WAV file, which is easy with `ffmpeg` or `sox`. However, the two files are different lengths, and I'd like to join them so that the *end* of the file matches, rather than the start.

So, for example, there are two files, `P0.wav` and `P1.wav`. I'd like to merge the two together so that P0.wav starts, and then P1.wav is mixed in so that both files end at the same time:

```
  <-------P0.wav----> file 1
      <---P1.wav----> file 2
```

I've tried both ffmpeg and sox, and both will merge the files down to a single channel, but the result is:

```
 <-------P0.wav----> file 1
 <---P1.wav---->     file 2
```

Is there way to achieve this using ffmpeg or sox, ideally "generically" (i.e. without having to example each individual file and work out the timings) so that I can throw it into a batch?

Comment: Dumb solution could be to reverse the files, merge, then reverse the result :^)

Comment: `man ffmpeg` ->  -itsoffset offset (input)
           Set the input time offset.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With full credit to @michaeljan for the inspiration, the answer is to reverse both files, merge them together and then reverse them again.

```
ffmpeg -i p0.wav -i p1.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]areverse[1r];[1:a]areverse[2r];[1r][2r]amerge[m];[m]areverse[f]" -map "[f]" output.wav
```

So that filter_complex magic:

1. Takes `p0.wav` and reverses it as `[1r]`
2. Takes `p1.wav` and reverses it as `[2r]`
3. Merges `[1r]` and `[2r]` together to `[m]`
4. Reverses `[m]` to `[f]`

.. and then `[f]` is the final file.

A small caveat is that the merge file is only as long as the shortest file: however, in my use case I actually wanted `p0.wav` to be truncated to match the length of `p1.wav` - if this isn't the desired affect then changing `amerge` to `amix` and using the [duration option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-amix) should fix this.